# What is the best stable ppa for Nouveau?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, nouveau

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to know if there are stable and updated ppas for Nouveau that provide bug fixes or should I stick to default? Maybe somebody uses those ppas with Nouveau and can advise something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. [Xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers) worked the best for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```